# OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader Hangs When using IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (CLI Driver) in .Net

Tags: .net, odbc, db2

I'm running into an issue when trying to use the IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (CLI Driver) in .net.  I've created a simple little test application which calls out to a DB2 database a retrieves some user attributes.  I'm running this from a 64bit Windows NT 6.1 server and have tested the connection to the DB2 server successfully via telnet, ODBC Datasource connect and via my test application.  I'm using OdbcConnection and OdbcCommand.  The driver in the connection string is the IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (CLI Driver).  After opening up the connection (OdbcConnection.Open()) I run ExecuteReader (OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()).  My application just sits there hanging for indefinite amount of time.  Anyone else out there experienced this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

I've not experienced this, but would it be possible for you to use IBM Data Server Driver Package (be sure to get 64bit version) as this is the IBM recommended client for .Net?

Otherwise, an error or poorly optimized SQL may be in the command you are using for the data reader.